# How can I change the colour of tab bar in Xcode 14 (beta 6)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode14

How can I change the colour of tab bar in Xcode 14 and how to put it into my code.

code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 1
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView(selection: $Selection) {
            Home()
            .tabItem { Label("Home", systemImage: "house.fill") }.tag(1)
            About()
            .tabItem { Label("About", systemImage: "person.crop.circle") }.tag(2)
            Products()
            .tabItem { Label("Products", systemImage: "bag.fill") }.tag(3)
            Gallery()
            .tabItem { Label("Gallery", systemImage: "photo.on.rectangle") }.tag(4)
            Contact()
            .tabItem { Label("Contact", systemImage: "phone.bubble.left.fill") }.tag(5)
            
            
        }
        .accentColor(Color("Green"))
        
    }
}
```

for some reason apple keeps changing how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```